# Uncaught InvalidValueError: not an Array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, google-maps

I wonder if someone can point me to right direction here, I'm working with Google maps trying to shade assigned Post Code areas to a user, if I hardcode the **latitude** and **longitude** it works perfect like this;

```
var triangleCoordsLS12 = [
        {lng: -1.558585,  lat: 53.796545}, 
        {lng: -1.558585,  lat: 53.796545},
        .....
];
```

but I'm trying to get the information from MySQL database vis PHP and JSON like this;

```
$.ajax({
          type:'POST',
          url:'test.php',
          success:function(data){
             var resultArray = JSON.parse(data);
               for (var i=0; i<resultArray.length; i++) {
                  var triangleCoordsLS12 = new google.maps.LatLng(resultArray[i].lat, resultArray[i].lng);

          if(location.uname == 'John Smith'){
            bermudaTriangleLS12 = new google.maps.Polygon({
                paths: triangleCoordsLS12,
                strokeColor: '#ff0000',
                strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                strokeWeight: 1,
                fillColor: '#ff0000',
                fillOpacity: 0.30
            });
           bermudaTriangleLS12.setMap(map);
        } else if(location.uname == 'Bruce Brassington'){
             bermudaTriangleLS12 = new google.maps.Polygon({
               paths: triangleCoordsLS12,
               strokeColor: '#FFcc00',
               strokeOpacity: 0.8,
               strokeWeight: 1,
               fillColor: '#FFcc00',
               fillOpacity: 0.25
             });
            bermudaTriangleLS12.setMap(map);                 
        }
      } 
    }
 })
```

I get an error `Uncaught InvalidValueError: not an Array` on these lines:-

```
bermudaTriangleLS12 = new google.maps.Polygon({
```

I know error says not an `Array` so how do I put the points in array? I'd be very grateful for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to construct the array first, and then use it when you create the polygon. In your code, you create a new polygon inside the "coordinates" loop, so you create a polygon with just one point on each loop.

```
//build the array
var resultArray = JSON.parse(data);
var triangleCoordsLS12 = []
for (var i=0; i<resultArray.length; i++) {
    triangleCoordsLS12[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(resultArray[i].lat, resultArray[i].lng);
}
//use the array as coordinates
bermudaTriangleLS12 = new google.maps.Polygon({
         paths: triangleCoordsLS12,
         trokeColor: '#ff0000',
         strokeOpacity: 0.8,
         strokeWeight: 1,
         fillColor: '#ff0000',
         fillOpacity: 0.30
});
bermudaTriangleLS12.setMap(map);
```

Pseudocode my example:

```
For each coordinate {
    add coordinate to array
}
construct-polygon(coordinate array)
```

Your code:

```
For each coordinate {
    construct-polygon(coordinate)
}
```

Comment: Also the error can be occurred when you pass **string** to the *`Polygon`* data array, so make sure that you have use **float** type